# OpenSSL Unresolved External Symbol LNK2019 When Compiling Synergy in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, openssl

First, let me start by saying I've read EVERY post, link, answer, etc I can find that points to Linking/External Symbol errors in Visual Studio/C++. With that said, here are the 27 errors I'm getting:

```
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_free referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::showCertificate(void)" (?showCertificate@SecureSocket@@AEAAXXZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::initContext(bool)" (?initContext@SecureSocket@@AEAAX_N@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol X509_free referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::showCertificate(void)" (?showCertificate@SecureSocket@@AEAAXXZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol X509_NAME_oneline referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::showCertificate(void)" (?showCertificate@SecureSocket@@AEAAXXZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol X509_get_subject_name referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::showCertificate(void)" (?showCertificate@SecureSocket@@AEAAXXZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_new referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::initContext(bool)" (?initContext@SecureSocket@@AEAAX_N@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_free referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl SecureSocket::~SecureSocket(void)" (??1SecureSocket@@UEAA@XZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_set_fd referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl SecureSocket::secureAccept(int)" (?secureAccept@SecureSocket@@AEAA_NH@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file referenced in function "public: void __cdecl SecureSocket::loadCertificates(char const *)" (?loadCertificates@SecureSocket@@QEAAXPEBD@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file referenced in function "public: void __cdecl SecureSocket::loadCertificates(char const *)" (?loadCertificates@SecureSocket@@QEAAXPEBD@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::initContext(bool)" (?initContext@SecureSocket@@AEAAX_N@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_get_peer_certificate referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::showCertificate(void)" (?showCertificate@SecureSocket@@AEAAXXZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_check_private_key referenced in function "public: void __cdecl SecureSocket::loadCertificates(char const *)" (?loadCertificates@SecureSocket@@QEAAXPEBD@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_new referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::createSSL(void)" (?createSSL@SecureSocket@@AEAAXXZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_free referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl SecureSocket::~SecureSocket(void)" (??1SecureSocket@@UEAA@XZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_accept referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl SecureSocket::secureAccept(int)" (?secureAccept@SecureSocket@@AEAA_NH@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_connect referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl SecureSocket::secureConnect(int)" (?secureConnect@SecureSocket@@AEAA_NH@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_read referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned int __cdecl SecureSocket::secureRead(void *,unsigned int)" (?secureRead@SecureSocket@@UEAAIPEAXI@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_write referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned int __cdecl SecureSocket::secureWrite(void const *,unsigned int)" (?secureWrite@SecureSocket@@UEAAIPEBXI@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_get_error referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::checkResult(int,bool &,bool &)" (?checkResult@SecureSocket@@AEAAXHAEA_N0@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_server_method referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::initContext(bool)" (?initContext@SecureSocket@@AEAAX_N@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_client_method referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::initContext(bool)" (?initContext@SecureSocket@@AEAAX_N@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_shutdown referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl SecureSocket::~SecureSocket(void)" (??1SecureSocket@@UEAA@XZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SSL_library_init referenced in function "private: void __cdecl SecureSocket::initContext(bool)" (?initContext@SecureSocket@@AEAAX_N@Z)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ERR_get_error referenced in function "private: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl SecureSocket::getError(void)" (?getError@SecureSocket@@AEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>SecureSocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ERR_error_string_n referenced in function "private: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl SecureSocket::getError(void)" (?getError@SecureSocket@@AEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>C:\Users\ME\Downloads\synergy-master\synergy-master\lib\MinSizeRel\ns.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 26 unresolved externals
```

Some background: I've downloaded [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) from their [GitHub](https://github.com/synergy/synergy) and built it without error. Getting it to build took a small amount of hacking because they don't officially support Visual Studio 2013, but not overly difficult. I also built is using the latest Qt instead of the one they provide on their site (2010) I'm also using OpenSSL from [SLProWeb](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), 32-bit full version.

Anyway, I cleared up a minor error or two in their code and tried to compile it first from command line, and second with VS GUI. Both spit out the 27 errors shown above. As I said, I've searched high and low trying to figure out what I've done wrong, but ultimately found nothing. I copied ssleay32.lib and libeay32.lib, with their .dlls, into the /ext/openssl/out32dll folder, where Synergy looks, which didn't work, so I pointed the linker additional libraries directory to it manually and also added it to the additional includes, and added the two .libs to Input>Additional Dependencies. Still no good.

In a last ditch effort, I added this to the top:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32MD.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32MDd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32MT.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32MTd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32MD.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32MDd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32MT.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32MTd.lib")
```

while also copying the rest of the libs into the out32dll folder. This proved that it know the files existed, but still refused to resolve the External Symbol issue.

To me, it looks like it isn't properly loading libeay32.lib, which contains the crypto portion of OpenSSL that the compiler complains about....

Comment: Actually, SSL_* functions should be in ssleay.

Comment: So both then? I know that crypto, x509, and err are part of libcrypto which is libeay32.lib on Windows. It's just odd because it isn't every function that doesn't resolve.